# Partial fraction decomposition of fraction with non-polynomial terms

Tags: partial-fractions

If I for example have a fraction

\begin{align} \frac{1}{(x-e) \space \ln (x)} \end{align}

can I use partial fraction decomposition to get an equation like this?

\begin{align} \frac{A}{x-e} + \frac{B}{\ln (x) }\end{align}

---

When I tried to do the math, I got

\begin{align} \frac{1}{x-e} + \frac{1}{(1-e) \space \ln (x)} \end{align}

which has the same form as the first equation, but it's a little wrong. I suspect I need a function $f(x)$ instead of $B$, but I don't know what that should be. I also think this might not be possible as I've only heard of partial fraction decomposition when there's polynomials involved.

Comment: i think this works only with polynomials

Comment: It's not really clear that the numerator $B$ should be a constant.  These rules are known when the denominator is a polynomial, but not necessarily for other types of functions - like $\ln(x)$.

Comment: @dannum Is it possible to derive what function the numerator $B$ should be?

Comment: It may be possible, but I do not know of any way to do this.